# Delete all rows from 3D numpy array which contains certain value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a 3D numpy array of such

```
position = 
    [[[ 12.86420681 825.87040876   1.           8.           0.        ]
      [753.26000819 280.1334669    2.           8.           1.        ]
      [ 51.6851021  330.65314794   3.           8.           0.        ]
      [661.07157006  78.15962738   4.           8.           1.        ]
      [878.59383346 550.5236096    5.           8.           1.        ]
      [774.49249941 942.74557677   6.           8.           1.        ]
      [301.20619756 206.50737851   7.           8.           1.        ]
      [240.50228642  91.21979947   8.           8.           0.        ]]
    
     [[  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
      [  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
      [  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
      [  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
      [  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
      [  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
      [  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
      [  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]]
    
     [[  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
      [  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
      [  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
      [  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
      [  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
      [  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
      [  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
      [  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]]]
```

On the first page of the array, it has some random values and all the other pages are zeros and I'm interested only on the 4th column of 1st page, which has either 1 or 0. I want to delete all the rows from all pages, if that row on the first page has the value "0".

I tried to solve this by giving the following code:

```
positionNew = np.delete(position, np.where(position[0] == 0), axis=1)
```

but I got this as the output:

```
positionNew =
    [[[753.26000819 280.1334669    2.           8.           1.        ]
      [661.07157006  78.15962738   4.           8.           1.        ]
      [774.49249941 942.74557677   6.           8.           1.        ]
      [301.20619756 206.50737851   7.           8.           1.        ]]
    
     [[  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
      [  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
      [  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
      [  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]]
    
     [[  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
      [  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
      [  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
      [  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]]
    
     [[  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
      [  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
      [  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
      [  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]]]
```

but I'm missing one of the rows, which has the value of "1", namely this one:

```
[878.59383346 550.5236096    5.           8.           1.        ]
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reconstruct your data exactly (please share code next time!), but this is a similar example:

```
import numpy as np

d1 = [[1,2,3,0],
      [4,5,6,1],
      [7,8,9,0],
      [2,4,6,1]]

d2 = [[0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0],]

d3 = [[0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0],]

a = np.array([d1, d2, d3])
```

You can use boolean indexing to select the data you want:

```
# for d1 (0), find where all rows (:) have a 1 in the last column (-1)
mask = a[0, :, -1] == 1
print(mask)

# for all of d1, d2, d3 (:), index the rows with the mask
a = a[:, mask]
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[False  True False  True]

[[[4 5 6 1]
  [2 4 6 1]]

 [[0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]]]
```